# Joining realm failed: HTTP response code is 401, not 200

Tags: linux, centos7, freeipa

I am using an ipa-server for centralised user login in my enviornment. i have  about 20 to 25 client machines to connect to this server. i was able to connect most of the client to the server using `ipa-client-install` command except 2 of then. my client machines are fedora 21 and my server is cenots 7.

when i connect my client machines to this server it gives an error message saying

`Joining realm failed: HTTP response code is 401, not 200
Installation failed. Rolling back changes.
IPA client is not configured on this system.`

Can any one help me out of this error. where did i went wront. have reassured there is no error in assigning dns server and hosts file. Renamed hostname adding it to domain .

regards.

Answer (score 1):

if your are using host files for DNS resolution, maintain the records so that FQDN name is first and short name is second.

For example, entries should be like

1.1.1.1    server.domain.com      server

and not

1.1.1.1    server    server.domain.com

Comment: you are right, its FQDN issue

Answer (score -1):

The solution to switching the hosts file order worked for me in a small lab setup that uses some local host files on the dnsmasq servers.

Comment: The question is rather old and this answer is not provide any additional help answering the question. Consider up voting the provided answer and leaving a comment rather than answering with a "me too" response.